# load csv file in mysql table using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command

Tags: mysql

I want to load csv file into mysql table.The query works fine but in csv row is like :

```
1000002,Kabul,"Kabul,Afghanistan",2004,AF,City,Active
```

Kabul and Afghanistan goes into 2 separate columns.below is my query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
    INTO TABLE '.$table.'
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
```

I want "Kabul,Afghanistan" in one column.

Comment: I believe you want to add `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` (i.e. a double quote `"` inside single quotes)

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to add

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

so that the loader knows to treat the quoted string as a single field.